# Setting a default value to a blank form in html.(Ruby, Sinatra, CSS)

Tags: html, css, ruby, sinatra

im very new to html and have a basic understanding and cant use java query or javascript yet. I am trying to give a player the option to fill in the player 2 name field to play a friend or leave it blank to play the computer in a basic game of rock, paper, scissors. I was hoping that if the field was left blank the param would pass nothing and the default value would be set in my Player Class.

Html:

```
<form id="name_form" action="/name" method="post">
  <label for="name" id="name_label">Enter Player Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="player_name" name="name" >
  <label for "name" id="name_label"> Second Player Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="player_name" name="name2" >
  <input type="submit" value="Play!" id="play_button";>
</form>
```

Ruby:

```
class Player

  attr_reader :name

  def initialize name = "Computer"

    @name = name

  end

end
```

Controller:

```
  post '/name' do
    player = Player.new params[:name]
    player2 = Player.new params[:name2]
    @game = Game.create player, player2
    redirect '/play'
  end
```

I was hoping something like the above would workbut i cant it to. Am i missing something? I would rather not use javascript yet. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params[:name]` and `params[:name2]` have an empty string `""` as a value. So, you are actually passing an empty string to your constructor. That's is "default value" is not used. If you want to use default value, then you have to omit an argument, like so:

```
Player.new
# => #<Player:0x007f9c5116b698 @name="Computer">
```

Also, note, passing nil will still mean that you are passing an argument with the value of `nil` and default value will not be picked up

```
Player.new
# => #<Player:0x007f9c5116b698 @name=nil>
```

That's why you need to update your code to this:

```
class Player
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize name
    @name = name.empty? ? "Computer" : name
  end
end
```

Comment: That's worked perfectly thanks! Any insight on why my default value in initialize didnt work?

Comment: Thank you so much!